# I completed a difficult task using a tool I developed before joining my employer. What is my obligation?

Tags: tech-industry, consulting

I am an employee at a Fortune 100 company. I just started at this job two months ago. Prior to this I was a consultant.

Today I had a meeting to start off multiple projects...the last project, which this post is about, is considered a bonus: it was "thrown out there" "in case you can do it."

To give some context, this is almost a "pipe dream" project for them. I am the third person they hired into this role since they created it. My two predecessors, my peer with a similar job role, our manager (who also managed the predecessors), our manager's manager, and our *manager's manager's manager* - who are all smart and capable, as far as I can tell so far - have so far been unable to complete this task.

They told me at the meeting that "We would really like to be able to do this, but so far, we've tried every which way and we can't seem to do it. It would be amazing if you could do it, but it's a plus, not an expectation." They gave details about what they tried, of course, but I'll leave those out here.

As they were describing it to me, I had some ideas of what to try- namely there was a project I worked on as a consultant, several months before I took this job, where I took an approach (both in terms of the method and the actual code) that seemed like it would work here.

When I got home, I tested it, not expecting much; after all, people much smarter than myself weren't able to do this. Since this is all on publicly available sources, I was able to do it from home without using company data or resources in any way. (Also, I'm salaried, so there are no "off hours" per se.)

It worked immediately. Some tweaking will be needed, but it's basically working already- I'm already at a stage that my leadership and peers claimed earlier today was not possible for us to accomplish.

Ordinarily, I would tell my bosses- but the method and code I used is proprietary- property of me, because I developed it when I was an independent consultant- nobody else was involved in its development and no one else has seen the code (my then-client saw and used the resulting data, not the code itself- the product was actually the data- not the same data as needed by my current employer but data that was collected in the same way).

Currently my employer is paying a 3rd-party vendor for the data. I don't know how much they are paying the vendor exactly but I've deduced it is at least $600,000 a year.

Right now, my plan is to just pretend I too couldn't figure out how to do this task (remember this is a bonus "would be nice" task), because I don't want to provide my employer with my proprietary method and code that is worth, based on my past earnings from this former client alone, about USD $45k/year, and evidently more in some applications. I *do* want my employer to have access to this data so they don't have to pay the vendor, but I don't want to screw myself out my work prior to this employer, either. One day I will leave this job, or who knows I may be laid off, and I would need to get back into consulting using everything I did before and more.

The argument could be made that my employer already paid for my skills when they hired me- but they did not pay for my proprietary tools I developed before joining them.

As far as I can tell, my options are: pretend I don't know how to do the (bonus) task; give my employer my proprietary tool for them to keep using even after I leave or they lay me off; ??? sell my employer the data but not the tool, same as the former client.

**What are the risks and tradeoffs to consider when making this decision? What other options are there?**

---

Update:

I told my boss about the solution and he laughed at me, saying that I must be mistaken and there is no way that anyone, especially me, would have been able to accomplish this task. So I guess my company doesn't want a solution anyway. oh well.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't lie.

Comment: This seems like a legal question. You should consult a lawyer.

Comment: Another option is to sell a licence to them for your tool - but talk to a lawyer to figure out how to protect yourself and your work.

Comment: I knew a couple of contractors that "sold" services to a large company - warning get a good contract sorted - you have something they need ... And **NO** they don't get it just because they hired you...

Comment: Remember that you have previously put in time and effort to develop the code. They did not pay you to develop it and should compensate you accordingly if they want to use it or have access to its output. You should also double check your contract with your previous work place to ensure you have the rights to redistribute the code/own it/use it commercially (it really depend on the contract).

Comment: Others are making $600.000 a year with similar software from only one customer, maybe you should rethink your career / business model...

Comment: Welcome to the site Max. As others have commented this is largely a legal question which we can't really cover. If you rephrase this to ask how you can broach the topic of setting up some kind of licensing situation, that's something this site can tackle. But figuring out the financially/legally optimal way to proceed is outside our area of expertise.

Comment: "there was a project I worked on as a consultant, several months before I took this job... that seemed like it would work here." To clarify - do you own the code you have used to solve their problem? If it was code you were paid to write for some other project, you might not, and that will make a big difference.

Comment: @Chris why is that? Usually you could charge 2 years of savings? So probably 1.2Mill should be the max.

Comment: The problem with all the answers is: if you tell your boss, they can just 'order' you to rewrite the tools for them on your current salary. I have no good answer for your problem.

Comment: As a "consultant" (before taking this role) did you act just as 'yourself' and were engaged directly by clients or were you a director/'employee' of your own company which was its own separate thing? (I'm in the UK but imagine it is similar in most places -- whereby I could work for a company as myself 'Jane Smith', or could supply the services of Jane Smith through my company 'seventyeightist data-munging consultancy inc.' or whatever.)

Comment: @lalala, then quit and offer them the data for $500k per year saving them $100k per year. And if it has happened twice, then it's probably something other people are looking for and a very profitable business opportunity has presented itself.

Comment: "It's basically working already." Famous last words in the software world.

Comment: Do you know what you signed when you joined the company?  There are some *really* nasty "non disclosure agreements" out there that basically ask you to list everything you invented before you joined the company, then agree that anything you did or thought of or whatever during your employment with the company is the property of the company.  Even if it was on your own time with your own money and tools.  So, I would be very, very careful here, they may already "own" some of what you've done.  Check your agreements before you do anything else.

Comment: @CramerTV - they currently think it's impossible. Demonstrate to them that it is possible but it'll cost them a cool half-mill, and they'll probably hire a new dev to write it from scratch for a fifth of the price you suggest the OP charges. Meanwhile, the OP is out of a job...

Comment: @BittermanAndy, Ok, so don't quit. 1) Start a company, you can do that in a week through legal zoom. 2) Hire a sales person (his sister, mother, father, whoever) to aproach this company and offer them the data they are interested in for less. If they bite, he's in. There are always challenges. If you want something, work for it.

Comment: I've been in this precise spot. My suggestion is don't let them know you have the tool. Don't even mention it. Don't ever let your source code touch their computers and/or network. Most likely you should not let their data touch your personal computers/networks either. That should give you a good idea of how to handle this. What's it worth to you if I solve this problem? Can I get a contract to go do that, completely orthogonal to my position with the company? And yes, get yourself a lawyer!

Comment: @seventyeightist I have an LLC.

Comment: In which case it’s not ‘yours’ but your LLC’s, which if there is interest, should help keep the separation as something that can’t just be ignored.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Talk to a lawyer first

Make sure you understand the legal ramifications of any actions before talking with your employer.  Do this ASAP.

## Research applicable company policies

Does your company have a conflict of interest policy that prohibits employees from acting as vendors to the company?  Make sure you know the rules.

## Decide what you're personally ok with

Don't give away the code to your employer unless you're ok with that.  Don't sell it to them (to use forever without further fees) unless you're ok with that. Decide what your boundaries are before talking to them. Above all else, decide whether you're willing to quit over this issue. You can't fully negotiate unless you're willing to walk away (in this case quit). You have to decide if you're willing to do so. If not, then it may be best to just give your employer the software (if they ask) rather than risk souring the relationship.

## Do your homework *quickly*

If your employer expects you to be working on the project in question already, then try your best to expedite investigating your legal options and the process of deciding what you want to do. Days are better than weeks. Hours are the best if feasible. You don't want your employer to be able to accuse you of not performing. It won't help your case if a legal battle ensues, and could get you fired. In addition, saying "I can solve this problem today" makes your story of having already developed the software more credible than if you wait a month to bring it up.

## Don't try to take advantage of your employer

Don't lie and don't try to gouge them for exorbitant sums of money just because you can.  While you might be able to charge a client X dollars, do remember that your employer is your *employer*, so the relationship isn't, and never will be identical to a contractor/client relationship.  That doesn't mean they have a right to your proprietary code or methods, but it does mean that you still need to treat them with respect and loyalty within moral, legal, and ethical bounds.

## Do protect yourself from being taken advantage of

Above all, talk to a lawyer if you haven't yet. Get everything in legally-enforceable writing when negotiating this with your employer. Don't give away the product and then demand a signed contract after the fact--protect yourself legally upfront before releasing any products or performing any services.  This is for your protection *and your employer's*.

## After all this, *then* talk with your employer

Once you've protected yourself legally and decided what options you're ok with, explain the situation and all options to your employer. Discuss your understanding based on legal and policy implications, and decide together what option to select *from the options that you've decided to put on the table*.  As mentioned before, do not put any options on the table that you're not comfortable with.

## Aim for a win-win

Do only what benefits both parties. If you can't reach a win-win, don't do the deal. Remember, at the end of the day you still have to work there, and you might want to be able to continue selling your product at some point in the future.  Don't do anything that jeopardizes either.

## Realize that you might have to head for the door

If the negotiation sours and you're not willing to work under your employer's terms, you may find yourself in a situation where it is better for you to quit your current job.  It's up to you to decide, *before beginning negotiations* whether you're willing to sacrifice your current job if it comes to it to protect your software.

Comment: My concern would be this: If you come in the next day with a solution, saying "This is code I wrote last year", they say "whoa, that's awesome!". If you spend ten days finding and talking to a lawyer before you talk to them, they say "You've had ten days to work on this problem on our nickel as a salaried employee, but you *swear* you did it last year? Oh really?" If I were OP's manager, my trust in OP would be at its peak very, very soon after I had told him about the open problem. Make it as easy as possible for them to trust you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Good point.  I would definitely do the lawyer work on my own time and dime, and start on the other tasks for now.  Only once I'd squared away the legal stuff on my end, would I start approaching this project, and then and only then do it on company time and money.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In a matter of speaking yes, though hopefully it would be more amicable than that.  The hope is that both parties either agree to a solution or both parties agree not to pursue it.  Though there's the definite risk that the employer would still want to pursue the project and OP wouldn't and would say no, which might end up with OP heading for the door.  So that has to be weighed in too.

Comment: @bob If he comes in the next day with a solution that he says he already had, they believe him and it's plausible to pay him for work he did *outside company time*, even though he is now a salaried employee. Because there just hasn't been time for him to write new code for this thing. If he comes in a month later with a solution and a lawyer demanding money for work that he *claims* he did before he was hired, he's may just damage his relationship with his employer and end up with nothing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's certainly true unless he can prove that he did it a year before.  I think this comes down to the professionalism of both OP and the company.  This is definitely a high-risk situation for OP.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Me too honestly.  I agree with you.  The hard part is that the bridge has already been crossed: OP already has the assignment and already knows how to solve it with OP's proprietary software.  So I'm not sure doing nothing is really a reasonable option.  To me it looks like OP either has to go forward realizing it may force them to quit, or OP has to go forward being willing to do whatever the employer asks.  It comes down to which OP values more, their current job, or their software.  And of course the right answer is up to OP.

Comment: I guess as always, you can't really negotiate with your employer unless you're willing to quit.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Would that cause issues for OP if they want to sell the service of using the software to solve problems for clients in the future?  Just wondering: if they charge client A $100k to solve a problem for them with the software (maybe the exact same problem as is being discussed here), and charge their employer $0 to solve a problem for them with it, could that cause issues, or would that be par for the course?

Comment: The other question is this: would the employer be ok with the arrangement: I'll take the data home, solve it on my equipment, push the data back onto your systems and give it to you? Wouldn't they ask for a copy of the software so they could solve such problems in the future or repeat/audit the analysis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94365/discussion-between-bob-and-joe-strazzere).

Comment: It does to me too.

Comment: Perhaps you could modify the answer to comment on the importance of speed?  It's possible to knock out the "get a lawyer, talk to the lawyer, decide on your strategy" parts of the exercise within 24 hours - not burning all that much of that precious, precious credibility time if you move quick.  Right now, it's only been a day since they introduced him to the idea, and he's got a weekend to cover the lawyer issues.  Getting a lawyer over the weekend might cost a bit more, but I'm sure it's doable.

Comment: Good point; I've edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 49):

> Right now, my plan is to just pretend I too couldn't figure out how to
>   do this task (remember this is a bonus "would be nice" task), because
>   I don't want to provide my employer with my proprietary method and
>   code that is worth, based on my past earnings from this former client
>   alone, about USD $45k/year, and evidently more in some applications.

Don't start what will be a business negotiation with dishonesty. Instead, prepare yourself properly for it.

> I do want my employer to have access to this data so they don't have
>   to pay the vendor, but I don't want to screw myself out my work prior
>   to this employer, either.

So, be honest. Make a detailed writeup of what your tool does (without giving the code away), outline the amount and complexity of work you've performed to make this, and outline that it is currently your own proprietary code from before you were hired.

State and outline how much this data was worth to your client, and outline how much customization you think this would need to fit your company's use case. Then ask them to make you an offer for the existing product.

> As far as I can tell, my options are: pretend I don't know how to do
>   the (bonus) task; give my employer my proprietary tool for them to
>   keep using even after I leave or they lay me off; ??? sell my employer
>   the data but not the tool, same as the former client.

There's a fourth and preferable option. You are honest with your employer and enter into a business negotiation for them to license the tool from you and make space in your schedule for you to code any customizations they need from it.

It's your code, under your ownership, built in your time and prior to any sort of assignment clauses you have signed for your current employer. This is no different then licensing a tool that provides this data from a vendor, only that you are the vendor now in this negotiation.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, NO! Do NOT price it according to what you spent developing it. Price it according to how much it saves or how useful it is to new company. If OP estimates company pays 600k a year for data, then OP's program is worth no less than (600k minus cost of input data) per year.

Comment: @Miech If you read my answer, I advise OP to not name a price at all. They should outlay what it took to make it and let the company make an offer. Which price OP would like to take is their decision

Comment: I read your answer, I think outlying what it took (cost) OP to make the tool gives company great starting position to lowball him.

Comment: Thats assuming that OP doesn't know the value of their work for the company (seems like OP does).

Comment: And don't disclose how long it took you to develop, as they'll get you to spend x months rewriting it for them from scratch, because x months at $y (of your salary) is much cheaper than $600k per annum, or even your lower charge. I'm not sure how I'd play this, having failed in the past with similar discussions.

Comment: If it's saving them from 600K/year cost, then it is (600K minus input data) is the *maximum* that it is worth.  You want to be on good terms with your employer, after all.  Yes, you want to get paid, and you should get paid, but fighting for every penny in the bucket will very quickly make it not worth their while.  OP can easily take a payday off of this one that will serve them quite nicely while *also* saving a significant amount of money for the company and making them happy that they "lucked into" hiring him.  Better to go for that outcome than to drive it all into bitterness.

Comment: Why bring up anything about how much effort to make it?  Highlight that the other members of the team have tried and failed .. and you have a fix.  See; no need to say how hard it was.

Bear in mind though, if they don't want to pay you for that product, they may just expect you to write it from scratch for them.

Comment: This is a legal issue concerning when the OP first began developing the application, and, most importantly, **if they were required to claim it as their own before being hired!** Doesn't matter if the OP started developing it 10 years ago or yesterday, it will belong to the company. That being said, the OP should not act alone on this and should not immediately try to negotiate with the company. Talk to legal first.

Comment: @Charles I've never heard of a scenario where an employer inherits all of your past work upon hiring. I've comfortable and aware that making software while hired can be gray area for what they can claim at least some rights to, but even that isn't an all-inclusive "we own everything you make". For my employment [US], it must pertain to something in the area I work in. If I make a video codec in my spare time, but I developed invoicing software for a living, they wouldn't be able to claim that software.

Comment: @Xrylite If you try publishing research and/or making a product commercial during your employ and it's not claimed at the time of hire, the company has no way of determining if you developed the content completely outside of your employ there (i.e., no company influences contributed to the process of your content development). In most cases, benefit goes to the company. Considering that the OP works for a Fortune 100 company and depending on how aggressive the management team is, if the OP just comes out and says, "I have an app that'll do this and I'll charge you $X much", it'll end badly.

Comment: @Charles "the company has no way of determining if you developed the content completely outside of your employ there" The fact that the code was used to generate similar data for a client several months prior to employment isn't evidence enough?

Comment: @DarthFennec Who says company X is willing to get involved in litigation just to help out an ex-employee? And how would OP prove that the work done for company X was carried out by that application? Is the application designed to include a kind of "watermark"?

Comment: @Charles If it's clear that OP was generating the same kind of data for both companies, would it not follow that he used the same tool for both jobs? I doubt a jury would buy "he wrote the same tool twice and then pretended to have only written it once" without some really good evidence, because that sounds pretty contrived. Good point about company X not wanting to get involved, though.

Comment: @DarthFennec Without knowing the actual details of the OPs application, it's honestly hard to say. However, the OP did mention that "some tweaking" will be needed in order to make it work. IMO, just from the information provided, it doesn't sound like a good idea for the OP to formally proposition the app to their company for additional compensation.

Comment: @Charles That would be trivial to prove in any sort of well set up shop. If OP uses any version control or even just has the files still, timestamps and invoices will prove that. I don't know of anywhere in the world where the new company could claim legal ownership of OPs code.

Comment: @Magisch I guess ownership addendums are just magic and fairytales then.

Comment: @Charles A company can't blanket say they own everything you did before you signed up with them, that'd be absurd, at least where I'm from. Even IP Assignment clauses only cover stuff done while under employment, not prior.

Answer (score 5):

You have three routes open to you.

1. Say you don't know how to solve the problem.
2. Solve the problem and become a hero at your new company. Explain to your manager how you solved it, using your previous experience. Ask for advice about how to make sure you get corporate brownie point credit for it (patent application, recognition, promotion, bonus, that sort of thing.)
3. Do number 2, and ask for them to recognize that the code is yours and you want to retain ownership of it.
4. Negotiate with them to license your code to them and get a yearly fee.

If it were me I'd go for item 3. Solve their problem.

The corporate brownie points can be worth a great deal long term, even if you return to being a consultant. It's worth considering.

Comment: To add to 3, have them sign a lawyer written contract that outlines ownership of the code, their use of it while your are an employee, and their use of it once the employer/employee relationship has ended.

Comment: 5. Open source the tool, put it up on GitHub/GitLab and let the world benefit from your experience

Comment: @Underverse Exactly. RedHat (owned by IBM) will be only too happy to benefit from your experience. Everyone else will be expected to pay. Giving away work for free is for mugs.

Comment: `ask for them to recognize that the code is yours and you want to retain ownership of it` is a **TERRIBLE** advice: you can't work on something **while employed by** the company and claim IP ownership **afterwards**. Even if you do it on **your own time**, you have to be up front as it will be difficult (or even impossible) to prove that you already owned the software.

Answer (score 1):

They are paying you for your skills and experience (Unless you join as fresher). So as per your experience, you should design and build the tool for them from scratch and don't give the code and your proprietary tool to them.

That's how it happens when you leave an organization right, you take the experience and skills with you, not the code and tool which you have worked on.

Or just tell them that you already have a solution ready and it cost you this much time and money ask the money to them if they are happy win-win for both, but this can go horribly wrong.

Comment: if you do that then you may have a hard time proving that you actually already had written the same thing before if they sue you for using the tool after you leave this company

Answer (score 1):

Since you used your previous work to do the job and you own copyright for it,

- Tell them honestly about your findings, and
- **Offer them to buy your previous work for an appropriate value.**
- If you are/were planning to keep profiting from your knowledge, either

  - **Set the price to include**

    - your projected earnings from this data-as-a-service within a reasonable time (if you are not planning to provide the service the same way you did), or
    - the estimated risk for your independent business from the potential of them becoming your competitors or from related work for them jeopardizing your business e.g. due to non-competition clauses (if you still plan to provide it)
    - (See e.g. [freelancing - My customer wants me to record a video of how I develop his software product - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110487/my-customer-wants-me-to-record-a-video-of-how-i-develop-his-software-product/110506#110506) for a suggestion how to evaluate the price for a trade secret); **and, as the other option,**
  - **Offer the same service to them** like to your previous clients, for an appropriate price
- Of course, they may be angry, but if the knowledge is worth so much more than what they would pay you for the time it would take you to complete this particular job, they will not be able to argue with the fact that their salary is not an adequate compensation for it.

The 2nd option would put you into an ambiguous position: you will be providing this service as a contractor but do the rest as an employee. But if it's as valuable to them as you said, they would almost certainly choose the first option -- since it's cheaper in the long run, would be easier for everyone and they would not alienate such a valuable employee as you are.

The price won't include your further tweaking done for hire but given its immense value for the company, that shoudn't make a difference.

It doesn't matter if the components are open-source and probably under free software licenses (but of course you need to mention any encumberances, if they apply, in the offer). Your job picking and combining them is what adds key value here.

If the first option is chosen and you will keep providing your expertise on this project, this may also be a reason to renegotiate your salary at the company since your value to it has just risen considerably. But if working on that project further does not require the likes of scientist-level domain expertise (i.e. something that can't be taught to an employee within a reasonable time), or if the work you were hired to do already requires that level of expertise (so your value didn't actually rise, you just saved your company a tremendous amount of time and effort), a one-time sale transaction would likely be a better deal for everyone since otherwise, they could prefer to rather teach it to someone cheaper.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere OP doesn't have to say that. Copyright is held by the developer who wrote the code - this is not a controversial idea. And that's what OP said he did. Copyright follows from that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. I don't know where you live but I believe here in California anything related to your employer that you come up with, even if done on your own time, belongs to that employer. On several jobs I have started I have been required to list "previous inventions" so they know that anything I created while employed with them belongs to them. I once left a job because it was in a similar vague field to work some friends asked me to do for their startup, so any product could legally have been claimed by my current employer.

I would immediately go and say "I have a solution to this, the solution belongs to me.". You can then negotiate whether they will give you some reward/bnus for that or tell you to re-invent it on their dime. But if you suddenly come up with the solution while you are employed by the company without telling them beforehand, then it belongs to them and you will get nothing and lose the right to use it in any other situation.

Comment: The OP says they developed it before they were an employee. And were contracted to do so as a consultant, that would be enough paper trail to show it doesn't belong to the employer.

Comment: ...and one hopes that the OP uses source control even for his personal codebase. It's hard to argue with a check-in that was made before the OP even joined the company.

Comment: My point was to be careful because even things you think might be your property, may not be. That company I worked for had a cadre of legal people to vigorously enforce IP and NDA contracts and often just the threat of litigation was enough; all the check-in logs in the world won't pay the $200/hour a lawyer would charge to defend you. The OP needs to tell his employer the situation now, and get a written acknowledgment of the situation so even if he gets no compensation he retains ownership.

Comment: I've never been asked to list previous inventions or anything of the sort. One wonders why anyone works for these companies with clauses like that.

Comment: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/pre-invention-assignment-agreements.html

Comment: Please cite your reference to California law.

Comment: @Tony There's a very simple way to f*** the $200/hour lawyers: Surely OP has a previous employer. Who also has $200/hour lawyers. All OP needs to do is call the previous lawyer and tell them that the new company wants the rights to the software that he wrote while working at the old company. They will see the $$$$$ signs.